# A From address must be especified, i need hel on this please

Tags: c#, email, send

Im having an error when i run the application "A from address must be specified" what is wrong in this code, do I need activate something?

```
public ActionResult contactProcess(string nombre, string apellido, string email, string consulta)
    {
        var nombreCompleto = nombre.ToUpper() + " " + apellido.ToUpper();

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(email);
        message.Subject = "Solicitud Procesada";
        message.Body = "Gracias por contactarnos, estaremos poniendonos en contacto con ustes en la mayor breveda posible";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "1234qwer");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(message);

        ViewBag.gracias = "Gracias por contactarnos" + nombreCompleto;
        ViewBag.texto = "hemos enviado un correo a la dirección" + email;
        return View("/Views/Formularios/contactResponse");


    }
```

Comment: you did not put your own email address. It should be something like this `MailMessage msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(EmailAddress, DisplayName, Encoding.UTF8) };`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the From address, you can make use of the constructor for this. try the following:

```
string toMail = "you@yourDomain.com";
string fromMail = "friend@friendsdomain.com";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromMail, toMail);
```

Take a look into the available constructors in the [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) class for more details